# Is there a portable version of the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows

I have Windows 8 and I'm stuck with Windows preventing me from installing WSL...
I know there are many tools that emulate Linux in windows but my target is to move to other software on Windows -software that depends on WSL- so I'm looking for a version without installer to avoid the OS saying it can not setup (since WSL is not available for Windows 8).

Is there any portable version for WSL (e.g : a zip archive) that can be set up without installer and contains all the necessary files ?

Comment: Try `cygwin`, installed folder can copy and use.

Answer (score 1):

No. WSL requires support straight from the Windows kernel, which is not present in Windows 8. You should probably use some of the available alternatives.

Comment: do you mean that for new versions of WSL ? I understand it but  I used to have Windows 7 and WSL was working OK then that same version no longer work with Windows 8 -I still doubt it's Microsoft policy, not a matter of kernel versions

Comment: AFAIK WSL was never available on Windows 7; what was available previously were various iterations of the POSIX subsystem for Windows NT, but that's a different thing - they are more like kernel-powered cygwin (so, a POSIX environment for binaries explicitly compiled towards it), while WSL is a full Linux ABI compatibility layer.

Comment: maybe you are right and I'm  confusing versions of Interix with WSL but can we add some layer to the kernel of Windows 8 to make it work with WSL ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to do setup ArchWSL from .zip and from .appx, but you must have:

Windows 10 1709 FCU x64 or later/ Windows 11 x64.

Windows Subsystem for Linux feature is enabled.

https://github.com/yuk7/ArchWSL

https://wsldl-pg.github.io/ArchW-docs/How-to-Setup